# Solana candy machine using metaplex / yarn install / node-gyp err?

Tags: node.js, npm, operating-system, yarnpkg

I'm trying to make solana candy machine now.
Environment:

- node 14.18.1
- npm 6.14.15
- cargo 1.56.0
- rustup 1.24.3
- yarn 1.22.17
- solana-cli 1.8.2

first I did

```
git clone https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex.git
```

And

```
cd metaplex/js/packages/cli
yarn install
```

then

```
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/yohan/metaplex/js/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

also

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/yohan/metaplex/js/node_modules/canvas
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.6
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

I had trying reinstall all. but it didn't work.
is it matter at node-pre-gyp? how can I fix this?